# IIS Express hosted site not setting HttpContext.User

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-identity, application-pool

I'm working on a process of migrating some old projects running on Windows Server 2003 to 2022. One of the websites I'm working on uses ClearTrust ISAPI Filter with some ASP pages to provide an STS which interrogates an ADAM server for authentication. Another developer has already upgraded this to .NET 4.8 but it was config only to get things running and it's still running WebForms. This isn't in scope for change at this point. My task is to extract the ClearTrust filter as it's unsupported and not compatible on 64 bit.

So my issue is that when I run the application I see the landing page and when I press the Logon button some decisions are made based on the user type connected to determine which Welcome page they should see. When I look at the live DEV environment it's running under IIS 5 with an App Pool Identity of NetworkService and the login page appears, but when I debug from Visual Studio under IISExpress the HttpContext.User property is always set to NULL so the user type determination step can't proceed.

[image]

To try to match the DEV environment I've created a Virtual Directory for the site under Project Properties page then found the `.vs\<projectName>\config\applicationhost.config` file and added this:
[image]

Not entirely sure if I'm supposed to change anything in the Properties panel:
[image]

Is there something I'm missing that will trigger the creation of a default IPrincipal for an unauthenticated user?

Comment: It really depends on when `Context.User` is called. In integrated pipeline mode, ASP.NET hooks deep into IIS native pipeline so the `User` object might not be available if authentication is not yet finished. As a quick test you can switch to classic pipeline mode first and see if that resolves the exception.

Comment: The pipeline is set to Classic in the properties pane, shown in that last image.

Comment: Make sure the content of applicationhost.config file is modified correctly, also you can try enabling windows authentication and disabling anonymous authentication to see if that works.